# What purpose is to place pins at bottom on STM32 discovery boards

Tags: stm32, development, stm32f4-discovery, pin-headers

What is purpose to have pins (pin header) on STM32 development board places at bottom? Arduino and similar have pins at top so you see the top of board and connect external peripherals by connectors that points up. But on the SMT32 Discovery (like https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/32f429idiscovery.html) connectors points down. Soo you can see on board peripherals like LCD display on top but connectors points at the opposite side. Because on some boards connectors have two rows you can't place it on breadboard.

Why STM32 boards have connectors pointing down, what is an advantage of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advantage is that you can stack boards downwards. If the connectors were on top the first add-on board would cover the display.

Arduino does not have a display, so there is nothing that has to be visible that would be covered.

Having all components on the same side (like Arduino) makes manufacturing easier and cheaper. In case of the discovery board you could not for example use wave soldering for mounting the connectors.

Comment: Most discovery boards do not have displays, the mechanical design predates that.

Answer (score 1):

> Why STM32 boards have connectors pointing down, what is an advantage of that?

Because some STM32 expansion boards connect to the bottom of the Discovery board. One example is the [STM32F4DIS-BB](https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/stm32f4dis-ext.html).